# Leaving Australia but still have a driver's license ... with an incorrect address?

Tags: driving-license, australia

When you move house in Australia, you have to let (well in Victoria State) VicRoads know your new address within weeks, or face a fine.

However, I'm looking to either go travelling for a few months, or move to a new country. My Aus license will still be current, but with an out-of-date address, as I'm leaving my apartment, but won't have a new address to put on.

What are you meant to do when moving overseas, in terms of updating this address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Address Requirements](http://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/Home/Licences/RenewReplaceOrUpdate/UpdateYourDetails/Addressrequirements.htm), an overseas address is an acceptable address. Unfortunately, according to [Change your address](http://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/Home/Registration/RenewCancelOrUpdateRegistration/UpdateMyAddress/), you can't do this change online (and apparently must do it by phone, post, or in person).

If you are going travelling, I'm sure a relative's address would be perfectly acceptable (and easier if it is also in Victoria).

Comment: Ah, the overseas options seems most reasonable, I can use my other (NZ) postal address.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that when questioned by police (they are allowed to ask), the address on your licence must match what you tell them. Any licence paperwork such as renewals or fines will go to,this address also.